# Microsoft.WindowsAzure Exception: The remote server returned an error: (503)

Tags: azure

After I deploy my web app to window Azure.I access my web app,the server return error 503.
it look like the server did not start, the file starter.cmd is empty(only @%*).

log:

```
2019-08-19T03:23:55.2310991Z,Using start-up script start.js from package.json.,,0

2019-08-19T03:23:55.2310991Z,The iisnode.yml file explicitly sets nodeProcessCommandLine. Automatic node.js version selection is turned off.,,0

2019-08-19T03:23:55.2467314Z,Selected npm version 6.4.1,,0

2019-08-19T03:23:55.2623494Z,The syntax of the command is incorrect.,,1

2019-08-19T03:23:55.2936133Z,The syntax of the command is incorrect.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\84.10807.4030\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd,,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kudu console (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net)  - Review the logs to fetch more on the error -Node.exe crashed – check d:\home\LogFiles\logging-errors.txt for stack trace and check win32 error code for more details.

In Azure App Service, the app is run in IIS using iisnode. To enable the app to run with iisnode, the root app directory contains a web.config file. The file is readable by IIS, and the iisnode-related settings are documented in the iisnode GitHub repository.

You could download the sample Node.js project from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/archive/master.zip and extract the ZIP archive and change based on your requirement.

Open index.js and find the following line:
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

App Service injects process.env.PORT into your application, so the code uses the variable to know which port to listen.

NODE.exe has a setting called NODE_PENDING_PIPE_INSTANCES. On Azure App Service, this value is set to 5000. Meaning that node.exe can accept 5000 requests at a time on the named pipe. This value should be good enough for most node applications running on Azure App Service. You should not see 503.1003 on Azure App Service because of the high value for the NODE_PENDING_PIPE_INSTANCES.
Kindly let us know, I have answered your similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36a2deca-da0c-455a-9f7f-75f9703c4346/microsoftwindowsazure-exception-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-503?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).